# Cannot build OSGi bundle for a Netbeans RCP application

Tags: javafx-2, osgi, netbeans-platform, osgi-bundle

When I try to build an OSGi bundle of a Netbeans RCP application (for example: the provided sample Feed Reader Application), it gives the following error:

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" /opt/developer/netbeans-8.0/harness/suite.xml:545: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[error] /opt/developer/netbeans-8.0/harness/osgi.xml:63: Could not prescan /opt/developer/netbeans-8.0/platform/modules/org-netbeans-libs-javafx.jar:
java.io.IOException: Unrecognized constant pool tag 18 at index 18; running UTF-8 strings: blah blah blah ...
```

Environment:

- Debian Jessie
- JDK1.8.0_45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that JavaFX is the culprit.

You can disable module *JavaFX Wrapper* as indicated below:

```
Projects/Feed Runner Application
  -> Properties
    -> Libraries
      -> (platform)
        -> (JavaFX wrapper)   [ ] included  (i.e: not included!)
```

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=250440